# airflow - add constant value to table when loading from gcs to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I have a dag with the following structure:

```
   loop by dates (date_var):
       -> loop by countries:
           -> process1 that outputs to gcs -> gcs to bigquery table 1
           -> process2 that outputs to gcs -> gcs to bigquery table 2
```

I want to add an identifier of the **date_var** to each processed data, but I have a couple of restrictions:

1. I cannot change the output of each process adding at that step the identifier for **date_var**.
2. I don't want to have a different table for each **date_var**
3. I want the countries and dates to run in parallel so I can only **append** data to the tables. ** WRITE_APPEND**

Any idea on how to add a column coming from a parameter at this loading step? Or any idea of how to solve this considering the 3 restrictions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @GabyLP, Can you provide the input and your expected output? Also the sample code you are using?

Comment: An option could be load data from gcp to a temporary table, then add the column using DML and finally load data from temp table to the final table